# Tensorflow ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've just used pip to install Tensorflow on my computer, which was successful (Win10). When I try to import Tensorflow in my code, it gives the following error messages.

Attempted to revert to tensorflow v1.5 as per other responses.

Python code:

```py
import tensorflow
```

Error:

```
  File "code-basics.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: This particular issue has been discussed in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: Do you use any environment management system, like Conda?